# Работа со числами и их изменение Python (палиндром)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется число Палиндром `12734554321` но в нем одна цифра лишняя. Нужно исправить и вывести исправленный вариант `1234554321`. Я пытался разделить число на двое и перевернуть число и сравнить, но это подходит для частных случаев. Нужно для всех случаев сделать.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def fix_palindrom(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        tmp = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
        if tmp == tmp[::-1]:
            return tmp
    return None
```

Примеры:

```
In [232]: print(fix_palindrom('12734554321'))
1234554321

In [233]: print(fix_palindrom('banana'))
anana

In [234]: print(fix_palindrom('12345'))
None

In [235]: print(fix_palindrom('12345547321'))
1234554321

In [236]: print(fix_palindrom('ananas'))
anana
```